# Minimal Polynomials of numbers from trigonometry

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

What is the minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q[x]$ of $$\alpha[k] = n\cdot \frac{a_{0}+a_{1}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})+a_{2}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})+\cdots+a_{k}\cos(\frac{k\pi}{n})}{b_{0}+b_{1}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})+b_{2}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})+\cdots+b_{k}\cos(\frac{k\pi}{n})}$$ with all $a_{i},b_{i}\in\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Q$ and $k \in \{1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$?

Is there a closed form for atleast $\alpha[1]$?

Comment: Is there something better than
$$m(x)=\prod_j(x-\alpha_j)$$ with $\alpha_j$ ranging over the Galois conjugates of $\alpha$?

Comment: what is $\alpha_j$?

Comment: The Galois group consists of the mappings $$\sigma_j:\cos(k\pi/n)\mapsto \cos(jk\pi/n)$$ with $\gcd(j,2n)=1, 0<j<n$. So $\alpha_j=\sigma_j(\alpha)$. Good luck with closed form!

Comment: So closed forms are tough?:(

Comment: The simpler case might be doable. IDK.

Comment: If you are willing to fix $n$, then getting a closed form would be doable, although having Maple or similar to assist would be a big help.  Maybe then proceed experimentally to try to pin down for $k=1$ and $n$ prime.

Comment: @JohnM I realize than. However, $n$ is variable here.

Comment: Even just calculating the closed-form of the constant coefficient of the minimal polynomial would be more or less equivalent to somehow writing down the "norm form" polynomial of a real cyclotomic number field of arbitrary modulus.  As long as the modulus, which here is $2n$, is allowed to vary, even a special case would likely be impossible to write down.